# If I fail to evade Dimensional Shambler, am I lost in time and space?

Tags: arkham-horror

Failing a combat check results in being lost in time and space, and this monster has no combat damage listed. If I fail to evade, that implies I suffer no damage nor do I become lost as it was not a combat check. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Failing an evade check results in exactly the same consequences as failing a combat check.  So if you fail an evade check to a dimensional shambler it results in you [being lost in time and space](http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/Dimensional_Shambler).

The [FAQ](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/FAQs/Complete_Arkham_FAQ.pdf) covers this for a different monster

> **Q:** If you fail an Evade check against The Beast (Mask
>   monster), does that count as failing a Combat check and
>   are you then devoured if you also fail the Horror check?
>
> **A:** Yes.